# RegEx alternative to state machine to get functions called in sscript

Tags: php, regex, state-machine

Imagine you have code that looks like

```
console.log(functioncall('Bang goes the' + 
' Olufsen (At least I think it does)'));
```

or

```
var_dump(functioncall("Please, for me"));
```

Without having to write a **state machine** and without running the script, is there a way to get all occurrences of `functioncall(everything_up_to_closing_parentheses)` in a script file using **PHP**?

Possible solutions involve RegExp, but I'm FAR from competent enough to write an expression that covers all possibilities.

Comment: Get all occurrences of a function without running it you mean?

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, sorry I shall make that clear now

Comment: you wrote **NB: functioncall() has a PHP and JS variant** that has no sense. if you are in js code - only js code is available, if you are in php context only php function could be called. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you use a php function named 'functioncall()' and also a javascript function named 'functioncall()'   ?  Man that must make your code confusing.  I'd call one of them functioncalljs()  or functioncallphp()